# Can XSModel object be obtained from a Schema Object?

Tags: java, xml, xerces, jaxp, xerces2-j

Using JAXP I can create a Schema object. e.g.

```
    Path schemaPath = ...;
    
    StreamSource source = new StreamSource(schemaPath.toFile());
    SchemaFactory factory = 
        SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
    
    Schema schema = factory.newSchema(source);
```

I am using Xerces.  Is there way to obtain the XSModel (org.apache.xerces.xs.XSModel) corresponding to the schema object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm no expert and I don't understand all the details, but: first find out what the implementation class of the `Schema` object is; see whether this has a method to extract a `Grammar` or `GrammarPool`; see if you can cast the result to a `SchemaGrammar`; and then the `SchemaGrammar.toXSModel()` method gives you what you're after.

Comment: Thank you, the `Schema` object implemented the `XMLGrammarPool` interface.